# How to test if a method of an object is called inside completion handler block using OCMock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a method:

```
@implementation SomeClass

- (void)thisMethod:(ObjectA *)objA {
    [APIClient connectToAPIWithCompletionHandler:^(id result){
        if (result) [objA methodOne];
        else [objA methodTwo];
    }];
}
```

Is there a way to verify `methodOne` or `methodTwo` will be called when `thisMethod:` is called? Basically I just want to stub that `connectToAPIWithCompletionHandler:` method. Right now I can do this by swizzling `connectToAPIWithCompletionHandler:` method. But I want to know if there's better way.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644772/ocmock-and-block-testing-executing), but it's using instance method while in my case is class method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)test_thisMethod {
    id mockA = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ObjectA class]];
    id mockClient = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[APIClient class]];

    // Use class method mocking on APIClient
    [[mockClient expect] andDo:(NSInvocation *invocation) {
        void (^completion)(id result) = [invocation getArgumentAtIndexAsObject:2];
        completion(nil);
    }] connectToAPIWithCompletionHandler:OCMOCK_ANY];

    [[mockA expect] methodTwo];

    [[SomeClass new] thisMethod:mockA];

    [mockA verify];
    [mockClient verify];        
}
```

Note that I typed this direct into the browser, but hopefully it's close to working.

Comment: thanks! it works! I just want to confirm my understanding, so for class method, the mock object doesn't have to be "fed" to the tested method. While instance method needs to be "fed" to the tested method. Is it like that?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way of thinking of it. The syntax OCMock uses is convenient, but does mask how different class method mocking is.